# How do I install the Profanity XMPP client on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin?

Tags: xmpp, jabber

Is there a PPA somewhere?

If not, what are the exact instructions to build from source?

I'm getting this error attempting it:

```
configure: error: libstrophe linked with expat is required for profanity
```

But there is no libstrophe in the repositories.

Comment: see http://strophe.im/libstrophe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building libstrophe from source worked. The full commands to build profanity on Ubuntu 12.04 are:

```
# Install repo dependencies
sudo apt-get -y install git automake autoconf libssl-dev libexpat1-dev libncursesw5-dev libglib2.0-dev libnotify-dev libcurl3-dev libxss-dev libotr2-dev libtool libexpat1-dev

# Install libstrophe
mkdir -p ~/.local/src/libstrophe
cd ~/.local/src/libstrophe
git clone https://github.com/strophe/libstrophe.git .
git checkout 0.8.7 # adapt to new version
mkdir m4
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install

# install profanity
mkdir -p ~/.local/src/profanity
cd ~/.local/src/profanity
git clone https://github.com/boothj5/profanity.git .
git checkout 0.4.5 # adapt to current version
mkdir m4
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```